# How to stop summing counter at exact value?

Tags: digital-logic, multisim, trigger

I want to stop summing counter at 25 decimal or 19(hex output) value while it's  begin summing from 1 to 31(1F in hex).So how can I make it ?[image]

Comment: Put a compare-to-25 circuit on the output, which will disable the counter (gate the clock)

Comment: @EugeneSh., where can I find it in multisim library ?

Comment: You can design it from logic gates

Comment: @EugeneSh., how to design "compare-to-25" ? What should I use ?

Comment: Draw a truth table. You have 5 inputs, and an output that will be `1` for a single combination (25) only. So it's a bunch of inverters and 5-input AND gate.

Comment: @Elvin Maybe... decode 25 into binary and then make *something* happen when you see that binary pattern?

Comment: Design from individual logic gates.  Start with determining what the bits are when you get to 25.

Comment: I agree with the others. You need to make something _"conditional"_ where once it reads 25, it will halt. Perhaps you will need to _"latch"_ it in place as well once it reaches 25.

Comment: More importantly - stop using ripple counters. Connect all of the clocks together, then produce the necessary logic to modify the JK inputs to produce a binary counter. THEN detect the desired stop count and modify the JK logic. It's more work up front, but trying to do almost anything worthwhile with ripple counters is a recipe for heartbreak.

Comment: is this a school assignment?